# insert null into number data type in plsql package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure something like

```
       create or replace package pack_body
         as
        procedure export(P_LOCATION_ID number
                         ,retcode OUT   NOCOPY   NUMBER)
         as
         ----body
        end;
```

I am calling this package in another package

```
pack_body.export(p_location_id => null);
```

At this line it is going into error:

```
Error(28412,5): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXPORT'
```

I cannot pass null into number data type variable ?

Comment: Try passing in the second argument, `retcode`.

Comment: Its an out parameter.... what should i pass.. in this

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass both arguments to the procedure:

```
DECLARE
  rc NUMBER;
BEGIN
  pack_body.export(
    p_location_id => null,
    retcode       => rc
  );
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this`retcode` is an `OUT` parameter,it means that a value is being returned from that particular procedure `pack_body.export` and is being assigned in the variable `retcode`

so while calling this procedure`pack_body.export`  you need to declare some local variable in your procedure of same data type in which the value of `retcode` can be assigned. Hence you getting this error.

You cannot use `null` as assignment target hence you need to declare a varible locally of same datatype